# Jupyter notebook ModuleNotFound

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I get this error when trying to execute the imports, i've tried to reinstall python3, ipython and jupyter-notebook, but i keep getting the error ModuleNotFound. I've tried googling and searching for an answer, but nothing  has worked so far. I'm new to jupyter-notebook and need it for a cou[image]rse.

Comment: First debug steps: 1. restart the notebook. 2. Did you install the Python package "matplotlib"?

Answer (score 0):

First, install matplotlib and numpy in your terminal:

```
pip install matplotlib  #add "sudo" before "pip" when you get "Permission denied"
pip install numpy
```

Then, choose the right Python version(i.e. kernel) for your notebook.